# For loop based on array length in Swift

Tags: ios, for-loop, swift

I have been trying to take the length of an array and use that length to set the amount of times that my loop should execute. This is my code:

```
  if notes.count != names.count {
        notes.removeAllObjects()
        var nameArrayLength = names.count
        for index in nameArrayLength {
            notes.insertObject("", atIndex: (index-1))
        }
    }
```

At the moment I just get the error:

```
Int does not have a member named 'Generator'
```

Seems like a fairly simple issue, but I haven't yet figured out a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to insert an object in an empty NSMutableArray, in this case you should use .addObject

Comment: If index is already occupied, the objects at index and beyond are shifted by adding 1 to their indices to make room.

Comment: Note that NSArray objects are not like C arrays. That is, even though you specify a size when you create an array, the specified size is regarded as a “hint”; the actual size of the array is still 0. This means that you cannot insert an object at an index greater than the current count of an array. For example, if an array contains two objects, its size is 2, so you can add objects at indices 0, 1, or 2. Index 3 is illegal and out of bounds; if you try to add an object at index 3 (when the size of the array is 2), NSMutableArray raises an exception.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You need to specify the range. If you want to include `nameArrayLength`:

```
for index in 1...nameArrayLength {
}
```

If you want to stop 1 before `nameArrayLength`:

```
for index in 1..<nameArrayLength {
}
```

Comment: @HoldOffHunger, I started at `1` so that the OP's `notes.insertObject("", atIndex: (index-1))` wouldn't crash.

Answer (score 18):

```
for i in 0..< names.count {
    //YOUR LOGIC....
}

for name in 0..< names.count {
    //YOUR LOGIC....
    print(name)
}

for (index, name) in names.enumerated()
{
    //YOUR LOGIC....
    print(name)
    print(index)//0, 1, 2, 3 ...
}
```

Comment: Just awesome. Working as expected.

Comment: it should be for i in 0..<names.count {.      "check for space after <"

Answer (score 4):

In Swift 3 and Swift 4 you can do:

```
for (index, name) in names.enumerated()
{
     ...
}
```

Comment: @MicheleDall'Agata I'm also from the C era. Great to have you back as a programmer!

Comment: Ah, just doing some Swift self training. The beginning has been atrocious! :-D Especially with those damn escaping closures..

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the Array's `indices`

```
for index in names.indices {
    ...
}
```

If you are just wanting to fill an array with empty strings you could do

```
notes = Array(repeating: "", count: names.count)
```